# Explanation of the definition of Euclidean metric.

Tags: differential-geometry, tensors, index-notation

I saw that one definition of Euclidean metric is

> There exists a coordinate $x^1,\ldots,x^n$, $x^i=x^i(z)$ such that $\det(\frac{\partial x}{\partial z})\neq 0$ and $g_{ij} = \frac{\partial x^k}{\partial z^i}\frac{\partial x^k}{\partial z^j}$ (sum over repeated index).

Then the book said that then the metric with respect to the coordinate $x$ is $g'_{ij} = \delta_{ij}$ by a change of coordinates. I wonder if you could explicitly explain how is the change of coordinate done?

Comment: Hint :  Use transformation rule for metric 
$$
g'_{ij} = \frac{\partial z^k}{\partial x^i} \frac{\partial z^l}{\partial x^j} g_{kl}
$$
with your definition of $g_{kl} = \frac{\partial x^m}{\partial z^k}  \frac{\partial x^m}{\partial z^l}$ above and the identitiy 
$$
\frac{\partial x^i}{\partial z^k} \frac{\partial z^k}{\partial x^j} = \delta^i_j
$$